# Spring Boot project Update operation is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, crud

Hello Fellow Developers,
I am learning spring boot and trying to code a crud operation. But unfortunately update operation is not working. I believe there is some lack of understanding from my end.
Please check my code below and any help will be appreciated.

Entity:

```
package com.travel.EasyTrip.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;


@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="Id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int Id;
    
    @Column(name="FirstName")
    @NotNull(message="required")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name="LastName")
    @NotNull(message="required")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name="MobileNumber")
    private String mobileNumber;
    
    
    
    public User() {
    }

    public User(int id, @NotNull(message = "required") String firstName, @NotNull(message = "required") String lastName,
            String mobileNumber) {
        Id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getMobileNumber() {
        return mobileNumber;
    }

    public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [Id=" + Id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", mobileNumber="
                + mobileNumber + "]";
    }
    
}
```

Controller:

```
 @PutMapping("/update")
    public User update(@RequestBody UpdateUser theUser
                 , @RequestParam("userId") int theId) {
        userService.update(theId, theUser);
        return userService.getUser(theId);
    }
```

UpdateUser Model:

```
package com.travel.EasyTrip.model;

public class UpdateUser {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String mobileNumber;
    
    public UpdateUser() {
    }
    public UpdateUser(String firstName, String lastName, String mobileNumber) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getMobileNumber() {
        return mobileNumber;
    }
    public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }
}
```

Service Implementation:

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void update(int theId, UpdateUser model) {
        User user = getUser(theId);
        user.setFirstName(model.getFirstName());
        user.setLastName(model.getLastName());
//      user.setId(theId);
        user.setMobileNumber(model.getMobileNumber());
        userDao.saveUser(user);
    }
```

DAO Implementation:

```
@Override
public void saveUser(User user) {
    Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    session.saveOrUpdate(user);
}
```

Database table creation:

```
create table Users (
    Id int NOT NULL auto_increment,
    first_name varchar(255),
    last_name varchar(255),
    mobile_number varchar(255),
    primary key (`Id`)
);
```

Not sure why the data is not updating. Help is needed here.
**Please find the link for the project incase you want to take look: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZZuYkYQ_uu0pnW9mYu12AFi3hNyTwblp/view?usp=sharing**

Comment: first ensure data are retrieved to the  theUser object and theId variable in the controller by using debugging.

Comment: Debug your application

Comment: I have done so, It seems update user is coming down to dao and then saveOrUpdate is not updating it with the new data.

Comment: I have given the project link it is a maven project, can you please check and let me know ? It will be very helpful for me. @Pawan.Java

Comment: Okay instead of "PutMapping" now I am using "PatchMapping" and it seems to working fine now.. Any Idea why "PutMapping" is not updating the data properly ? @Pawan.Java

Comment: Okay instead of "PutMapping" now I am using "PatchMapping" and it seems to working fine now.. Any Idea why "PutMapping" is not updating the data properly ? @KMS

Comment: PUT mapping is used for replace an existing resource entirely. PATCH mapping is used for partial update. @Koushik ruidas